# How to set draggable bounds for a polygon - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a polygon that can be resized as required and dragged/moved around the scene as desired. However, my question is how can I stop it from being dragged over buttons or my treeview list? Here is my code:

```
public Polygon cfp(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Polygon fp = new Polygon();
    ObjectProperty<Point2D> mousePosition = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    //Set the anchor points for the template layout
    fp.getPoints().setAll(
            350d, 50d,
            700d, 50d,
            1050d, 50d,
            1050d, 350d,
            1050d, 650d,
            700d, 650d,
            350d, 650d,
            350d, 350d

    );

    //Allow the Floor plan to be draggable around the screen
    fp.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
        }
    });

    fp.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mousePosition.get().getX();
            double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mousePosition.get().getY();
            fp.setLayoutX(fp.getLayoutX()+deltaX);
            fp.setLayoutY(fp.getLayoutY()+deltaY);
            mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
        }
    });
    //Set the colour and properties of the template layout
    fp.setStroke(Color.DARKRED);
    fp.setStrokeWidth(4);
    fp.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
    fp.setFill(Color.MINTCREAM);
    container.getChildren().add(fp);
    container.getChildren().addAll(createAnchors(fp, fp.getPoints()));
    return fp;
}

private ObservableList<Anchor> createAnchors(Polygon polygon, final ObservableList<Double> points) {
    ObservableList<Anchor> anchors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {

        final int idx = i;
        DoubleProperty xProperty = new ListWriteDoubleProperty(points, i);
        DoubleProperty yProperty = new ListWriteDoubleProperty(points, i + 1);

        //Bind the anchors to the polygon, so if its moved so are they
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(Color.BLACK, xProperty, yProperty);
        anchor.layoutXProperty().bindBidirectional(polygon.layoutXProperty());
        anchor.layoutYProperty().bindBidirectional(polygon.layoutYProperty());

        xProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldX, Number x) {
                points.set(idx, (double) x);
            }
        });

        yProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldY, Number y) {
                points.set(idx + 1, (double) y);
            }
        });
        anchors.add(anchor);
    }
    return anchors;
}

//Creating circles to mark the anchor points to help users know where to modify from
class Anchor extends Circle {
    private final DoubleProperty x, y;

    Anchor(Color color, DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y) {
        super(x.get(), y.get(), 5);
        setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        setStroke(color);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        x.bind(centerXProperty());
        y.bind(centerYProperty());
        enableDrag();
    }

    //Make the circle node movable with mouse drag
    private void enableDrag() {
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
        setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
                dragDelta.x = getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
                dragDelta.y = getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
                getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            }
        });
        setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        });
        setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
                if (newX > 0 && newX < getScene().getWidth()) {
                    setCenterX(newX);
                }
                double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
                if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
                    setCenterY(newY);
                }
            }
        });
        setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                }
            }
        });
        setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // records the x and y co-ordinates.
    private class Delta {
        double x, y;
    }

}
```

Here is my problem:

[image]

the scene where the polygon generates has an Anchor pane, the treeview is in a HBox and so are the buttons if that helps anyone.

Comment: I haven't coded JavaFX yet, but isn't the polygon restricted to a 'pane'? Can you not break the master window into two 'panes'? One for the buttons, horizontally across the bottom, and one for the polygon area?

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason I can drag it all around the window. The buttons are in a HBox and so is the TreeView, so I normally would assume the polygon could only be dragged around its parent pane, but it is not the case :/

Comment: Can you hardcode in X,Y extremes for the polygon? Therefore restricting it to its parent pane?

Comment: Possibly, I don't know how to do that though?

Comment: You would have to get the boundary positions from the parent object and then make sure you haven't crossed those boundaries either while the mouse is dragging, or when the mouse is released. Doing it while dragging will keep it from going outside at all. Doing it when released would snap it back into place. Again I haven't used JavaFX so I really can't whip you up any code.

Comment: Thanks for your response Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What is Happening*

Your check for the drag points for the anchor are based upon the scene dimensions rather than the dimensions of the parent container of the polygon.

*How to Fix it*

Change your checks to be based upon the parent container dimensions.

From:

```
setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
        if (newX > 0 && newX < getScene().getWidth()) {
            setCenterX(newX);
        }
        double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
        if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
            setCenterY(newY);
        }
    }
});
```

To:

```
setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
        if (newX > 0 && newX < getParent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth()) {
            setCenterX(newX);
        }
        double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
        if (newY > 0 && newY < getParent().getLayoutBounds().getHeight()) {
            setCenterY(newY);
        }
    }
});
```

Ensure that your parent is a resizable parent (e.g. a Pane and not a Group), otherwise the parent won't automatically expand to fill the available area in which the polygon can be placed.

*Additional Concerns*

If you resize the scene so that the area in which the polygon can be rendered is smaller than the size of the polygon, then the polygon will still overflow the available bounds (as they have now shrunk smaller than the size of the polygon).  There a couple of ways you could handle that situation.

1. You could place the polygon in a ScrollPane, so that the user can scroll around if the currently viewable area gets too small.   This is probably the preferred solution, but is a bit more complicated to implement well (and it is isn't really the question you asked).  I won't provide example code for this at the moment.
2. You can apply a clip to the parent container so that it does not draw outside the visible area.  For example if your container Pane for the polygon is named polyPane:

   ```
   Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
   clip.widthProperty().bind(polyPane.widthProperty());
   clip.heightProperty().bind(polyPane.heightProperty());
   polyPane.setClip(clip);
   ```

Content sourced from StackOverflow requires [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed everything you said and stuck with the rectangle clip. Much appreciated